# Can an Aegis blow through his PP to overcharge his astral suit's Crystallized Weapon ability?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, psionics

Can an Aegis blow through his PP to and over charge his astral suits Crystallized Weapon ability? Like 30 PP for 30d6 of melee damage?

Empowered Blast has a scaling damage of 1 PP per 1d6 of damage. Since that one ability can do it, is there a similar effect of scaling damage for Crystallized Weapon, since they are both damaging type abilities? CW doesn't say you can't, so can I blow 30 PP for one good shot with 30d6 bonus?

So, can I use more PP for the Crystallized Weapon Aegis Suit mod to increase damage?

Answer (score 3):

No. The amount of PP you can spend on it is specific and has a listed duration. The similarity does not imply that the object is treated exactly the same. You are limited to exactly 2 PP and exactly +2d6 damage, but you can repeatedly spend another 2 PP every time you use the effect.